# ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, karma-runner, commonjs

I'm running tests using karma and one dependency of my project has a dependency on es-cookie and it seems to be giving me problems when running the tests.

I tried adding a commonjs preprocessor but it gives a syntax error probably because commonjs doesn't work with the other files. I tried chaining it with another preprocessor but it still doesn't work.

`preprocessors: {
   'packages/**/test/**/*.test.js': ['globals'],
   'node_modules/**/*.js': ['commonjs'],
},`

The tests should run smoothly but this error pops up when there is no commonjs preprocessor

Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
  at node_modules/es-cookie/src/es-cookie.js:17:1

ReferenceError: exports is not defined

**UPDATE:**

This was the problematic line:

`exports.__esModule = true;`

I tried changing it to

`export const __esModule = true;`

And all my tests ran successfully. However, is it allowed to change a node module dependency's code, and is there a way to preprocess it in Karma?

Comment: check the content of `node_modules/es-cookie/src/es-cookie.js`

Comment: I checked it and it's a CommonJS module. If I convert it to an ES6 module, my tests run fine. However, I shouldn't really modify the code of a node module right?

Comment: well, no ... you're right, you don't want to do that

Comment: Why are your tests `'globals'`? Wouldn't they also be CommonJS?